# Accelerate framework vDSP_vtabi mistake in documentation?

Tags: accelerate-framework

In documentation for [vDSP_vtabi](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_vtabi) function there is a formula for output vector calculation (assuming stride for D is equal 1):

```
D[n] = (1 - r) * C[q] + r * C[q - 1]
```

So, i wrote sample code in Swift:

```swift
var A: [Float] = [-1.6, -1, 0, -1, 0.5, 1.6] // Expected in range [-1.6, 1.6]
var S1 = 1.25 as Float
var S2 = 2 as Float
var C: [Float] = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7]
var D: [Float] = Array<Float>(count: 8, repeatedValue: Float(0))
vDSP_vtabi(&A, 1, &S1, &S2, &C, 5, &D, 1, 6)
D
// Prints [0.1, 0.175, 0.3, 0.175, 0.4875, 0.7, 0, 0]
```

Then decide to calculate results by the hands. And actually unable to calculate when `q = 0`. Because `C[q - 1] => C[-1]` is not exists (index out of range).
I believe that correct formula should be following (instead of `C[q - 1]` should be `C[q + 1]`:

```
D[n] = (1 - r) * C[q] + r * C[q + 1]
```

Calculating Table lookup in Matlab also proof this:

```matlab
%% Input signal
A = [-1.6, -1, 0, -1, 0.5, 1.6]; %% Expected in range [-1.6, 1.6]

%% Lookup table parameters
F = 1.25; %% Scale
G = 2; %% Offset
C = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]; %% Lookup table

%% Calculation
p = F * A + G; %% 0 0.7500 2.0000 0.7500 2.6250 4.0000
q = floor(p); %% 0 0 2 0 2 4
r = p - q; %% 0 0.7500 0 0.7500 0.6250 0
D = (1 - r) .* C(q + 1) + r .* C(q + 1 + 1); %% '+ 1' Because arrays indexed from 1 in Matlab
%% D = (1 - r) .* C(q + 1) + r .* C(q + 1 - 1); %% According to vDSP_vtabi documentation. Fails with 'Subscript indices ...' error
disp(D);
%% Prints 0.1000 0.1750 0.3000 0.1750 0.4875 0.7000
```

Do you have similar results?
Is it really mistake in documentation for [vDSP_vtabi](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_vtabi) function?
Thanks!

Comment: Apple updated documentation and closed related bug (20152462) on 12-Nov-2015.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're correct that the documentation should read "(1-r)C[q] + rC[q+1]".  I've filed a radar to report the bug.

I should also note that the function is correctly documented in the header (vDSP.h):

```
/* These compute:
for (n = 0; n < N; ++n)
{
    p = S1[0] * A[n] + S2[0];
    if (p < 0)
        D[n] = C[0];
    else if (p < M-1)
    {
        q = trunc(p);
        r = p-q;
        D[n] = (1-r)*C[q] + r*C[q+1];
    }
    else
        D[n] = C[M-1];
}
*/
```